# How to specify that what followsa given text is a spelling dictation in Grammar file in sapi?

Tags: windows, speech-recognition, sapi

I am using Sapi 5.4 and I am trying to get the persons name which is spoken by user but it has a very poor recognition with names so I would like to enter the name by spelling Dictation that is like J-O-H-N and presently my grammer for taking name input is this

```
 <RULE ID="VID_InputType">
    <L PROPID="VID_InputType">
      <DICTATION MAX="INF"/>
    </L>
</RULE>
```

How could I mention spelling Dictation my modifying this grammar?

Answer (score 1):

If you load a dictation grammar with a specific topic into a reco context, then any rules that have a DICTATION element will use that topic.

This also implies that you can't have multiple dictation topics active within a single reco context; if you need multiple dictation topics active, they have to be in separate reco contexts.

So - you don't modify your grammar at all.

Instead, in your setup code, after loading the grammar, call

```
ISpGrammar* pGrammar;
// set up grammar
// now load dictation topic
hr = pGrammar->LoadDictation(L"Spelling", SPLO_STATIC);
```